# How to automate an Image Chart which is developed using Microsoft Chart Control using any automation tool?

Tags: vbscript, bar-chart, qtp, mschart

We have a requirement to verify whether the image bar chart values which are displayed in the web page are matching the expected values.

Below are the image chart properties in QTP with enabled addins like ActiveX, Web, ASPAjax, Dojo, GWT, YahooUI, WPF & Silver Light.

```
Class: Image
file name: ChartImg.axd?i=chart_75c762f28e394edeba3863d63bae9150_0.png&g=14f7f32133d74b6caaffe977533cd3a0
html id: ContentPlaceHolder1_Chart1
html tag: IMG
image type: Plain Image
name: Image
OUterhtml: <IMG style=height:300px;width:750px;border-width:0px; alt= src=/ChartReport/ChartImg.axd?i=chart_75c762f28e394edeba3863d63bae9150_0.png&g=14f7f32133d74b6caaffe977533cd3a0 id=ContentPlaceHolder1_Chart1>
url: {empty}
text:{empty}
```

Below are the details captured in firebug.

```
img id="ContentPlaceHolder1_Chart1"
style="height:300px;width:750px;border-width:0px;"
alt="" 
src="/ChartReport/ChartImg.axd?i=chart_75c762f28e394edeba3863d63bae9150_0.png&g=14f7f32133d74b6caaffe977533cd3a0"
```

I have enabled all possible addins of QTP 11 and tried to retrieve the text from the Chart image but was unsuccessful. I have checked with the developers of this AUT, they informed me that they have used microsoft chart controls and hence it will only be displayed as an image. I tried using many online ocr conversion tools but all I could see was the heading of the image alone. Is there any way to fetch the Image bar chart values using any automation tool?

Comment: Yes, there probably is. What have you tried?

Comment: I have tried with QTP 11 but couldn't find one proper solution. Could you please update on the possible solution.

Comment: I can´t see what you´ve tried if you don´t post it. Post the not-so-proper solution attempt, and we´re talking.

Comment: Hi Thomas. Maybe you should edit your question to include that last comment, it would make things clearer and probably increase the probability you get answered.

Comment: Thanks Vincent, I have updated the question as per your suggestions.